# disable and enable button in jquery after server event

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i need  to  disable   the button  during  the click  and  need   to  enable   after my server  side  event is  done
  right now  my code  looks   like this

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script  type ="text/javascript" >


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.saveButton').bind("click", function(e) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
        return true; //causes the client side script to run.
    });
});
</script>
//this  works  finr  for disableing the   button
//how  to enable  the  button  from disabled  to enable  after my server  side  event as  executed

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  CssClass="saveButton"  Text="Button" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"  CssClass="saveButton"  Text="Button" 
            onclick="Button2_Click" /> 

//Server   side  events
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch()
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        //once  my    control  reaches  here  i need   to enable  my save  from disabled to enabled stae 
        // can we  do this in jQuery
    }
}
```

looking for this  code  from PAST 2  DAYS
any solution on this  would  be great thank you
thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) method on your `Button1_Click` event, to add client scripts from the server-side:

```
var enableButton = "$('.saveButton').removeAttr('disabled');";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page.GetType(), "EnableButton",
                                            enableButton, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the core issue here is your understanding of the page lifecycle, you might want to read up on it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx.

It looks like you don't necessarily want to post the page back.  Consider updating the server using jQuery ajax and in the callback from that, re-enable the button.

Alternatively, this will re-enable the button after 5 seconds (after postback(hopefully!))

```
$(document).ready(function()
    { $('.saveButton').bind("click", function(e) {
                        $(this).attr("disabled", "true"); 
                       setTimeout(function(){$(this).removeAttr("disabled");}, 5000);
                        return true; 
                        }); 
    });
```

Or, at the end of your button click event write into a literal control something like this:
    "$(document).ready(function(){$('jQueryButtonSelector').removeAttr('disabled');});"

Or do the same using response.write()

Comment: hey  what is happening here  is  the button is getting disabled fine  once i click the button.but now it is not calling  my server  side  event only 
i.e
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
///  my code 
 }

Answer (score 0):

I ran into issues with the other answers not calling server side event once disabled, to solve I asynchronously disabled the button.

**Client**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitButton" ValidationGroup="DynamicForm" OnClientClick="disableButton(this);" />
<script>
    function disableButton(sender) { // Disable to prevent duplicate submission. Enabled in code behind
        if (Page_ClientValidate("DynamicForm")) {
            setTimeout(function () { $('#<%= submitButton.ClientID%>').attr("disabled", "true"); }, 0); // Asynchronously disable, otherwise disabled button won't submit first time
        }
     }
</script>
```

**Server**

```
Private Sub submitbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submitButton.Click
    ...
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "EnableButton", "$('#" + submitButton.ClientID + "').removeAttr('disabled');", True)
End Sub
```